# how to read object from servlet in android

Tags: java, android, servlets

I am developing a android application that has to talk with the servlet to access the database. I want to pass the object from servlet to my android application.

This my servlet code to send object.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    response.setContentType("text");

    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        java.sql.Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Database");
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();

        PrintWriter p = response.getWriter();

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from employee where PS="+id);

        while(rs.next()){
            Employee e = new Employee();
            e.setId(rs.getString("ID"));
            e.setPs(String.valueOf(rs.getDouble("PS")));
            e.setName(rs.getString("Emp_name"));
            e.setDept(rs.getString("Dept"));

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(e);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How should i read the object in my android application.
Thanks.

Comment: 1) content type should be something more adequate than `text`. 2) It looks like you want to write more than one object in the while loop. 3) **Never ever** concatenate SQL commands with values that come from the HTTP client, use a prepared statement. 4) You have to actually write the `ObjectOutputStream` byte buffer to the client using `response.getWriter().write(...)` methods. 5) On the client you could use an `ObjectInputStream`

Comment: @UdoKlimaschewski: you spoke from my heart... Also, for web communications, why not use something standardized, like JSON, XML, or even Google Protocol Buffers?

Comment: @ppeterka: Would have been also my choice, writing serialized objects looks a bit spooky, but should work. As long as both sides speak the same Java.

Comment: @UdoKlimaschewski 'As long as both sides speak the same Java': That is something I'm very very afraid of... :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do various things to solve this problem

a)Use DAO practice [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) Read it to understand it basically it divides the implementation of your code into different segments and classes for your ease.
But if you dont want to go through all that trouble You can do some thing like.
a.) Create a separate java class where you write all the methods to deal with the Db like insert,select etc.. 
e.g if your loggin in the user.. than the method would be like this..

```
public int AuthenticateUser(String un, String pw, String phn) {
        System.out.println("I m in this method");
        Connection conn = (Connection) DBConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
        Statement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        if (conn == null) {
            System.out.println("Connection error");
            check = -1;

        }


        try {
            String authenticatequery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = '"+un+"' && password =  '"+pw+"' && phoneno = '"+phn+"'";


            System.out.println(authenticatequery);
            pstmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery(authenticatequery);
            System.out.println("I m in above try catch");

            // pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(authenticatequery);

            // rs = pstmt.executeQuery(authenticatequery);


            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("I am in rs method");
                UserInfo  info = new UserInfo();
                rs.getString(1);
                rs.getString(2);
                rs.getString(3);
                //info.setUsername(rs.getString(un));
                System.out.println("i have the username" + un);
                //info.setPassword(rs.getString(un));
                System.out.println("I have got the password " + pw);

                System.out.println("I have got the password " + phn);

                System.out.println("User Exist");
                check = 1;
            } else {

                System.out.println("No user found");
                check = 0;
            }

            // rs.close();
            // pstmt.close();
            // conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Exception-internal error");
        } finally {

            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                    pstmt.close();
                    conn.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

}
    return check;



}
```

Notice the int variable "check" if the method runs correctly it will return '1' else '0'.. Now u can use this check for your advantage and send it to your android app via servlet like this..

```
protected void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //String username = request.getParameter("username");
    //  String password = request.getParameter("password");
        //UserInfo uinfo = new UserInfo();

    // uinfo.setUsername(username);
    // uinfo.setPassword(password);



        System.out.println("I am in process");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          String un, pw,phn;

          un = request.getParameter("Usrnm");
          System.out.println(un);
          pw = request.getParameter("pwd");
          System.out.println(pw);

          phn = request.getParameter("phn");
          System.out.println(phn);

            Authenticate auth = new Authenticate();
            int check = auth.AuthenticateUser(un, pw,phn);
            System.out.println("My result is" + check);
          if (check==1){

              out.print(1);
          }  else{
               out.print(0);
              }
              }
    }
```

In your android app you can call the the response object using the code below, do add custom http client class for the comunitcation.

```
response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://192.1..11../HelloWorldServlet/LoginDriverServlet", postParameters);
```

Now  you can play with the response object and mould it to suit your needs

```
if (res.equals("1")) {

                        Log.e("CHeck4 response","i m here");
                        Log.e("CHeck response", res);
                        //error.setText("Correct Username or Password");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SetStatus.class);

                        startActivity(intent);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_status);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loggin In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if(res.equals("0")) {
                        //error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");
                        Log.e("CHeck3 response", "i m here");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent();


                        //Username or Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }



Hope you get it..otherwise coments are welcomed :)
```